# How can I set a variable on a _Layout page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a view and I want to use a layout page. In the layout page I want to have a conditional banner which some of the view will turn on/off. Just wondering how I can do this?

I have this in the _Layout.cshtml page...

```
@if (ShowBanner){

   <h1>banner</h1>

}
```

I'm wondering how I can turn this on/off from my MVC View page? Or whether this is the right thing to do at all? I mean if I declare that variable in the View page surely the master doesn't know about it? How do the two communicate through c#? Do I use the Viewbag? Rather not.

I know with forms its all about referencing the Page or Master member, just cant quite seem to see it with MVC...

Any help much appreciated...

Thanks
Pete

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm with you, Exitos: I avoid using `ViewBag` too.  Aside from the silly name, I dislike the weak typing that comes along with it.  There is a solution, but it's kind of involved, so bear with me.

First, create a class to store the "display hints" that are to be passed to the layout.  I creatively call this class "DisplayHints":

```
public class DisplayHints {
  // anything that you want passed from a view to the layout goes here
  public bool ShowBanner { get; set; }
}
```

Then, create a class deriving from `WebViewPage<T>` that will be the new base class of your views.  Note how we have a property called `DisplayHints` that's stored in `ViewData` (which is available to the controller, the view, and the layout):

```
public abstract class MyViewPage<T> : WebViewPage<T> {
  public DisplayHints DisplayHints {
    get {
      if( !ViewData.ContainsKey("DisplayHints") )
        ViewData["DisplayHints"] = new DisplayHints();
      return (DisplayHints)ViewData["DisplayHints"];
    }
  }
}
```

As a commenter pointed out below, `ViewData` is weakly-typed, just like `ViewBag`.  However, there's no way I know of to avoid storing *something* in `ViewData`/`ViewBag`; this just minimizes the number of weakly-typed variables to one.  Once you've done this, you can store as much strongly-typed information in `DisplayHints` as you want.

Now that you have a base class for your views, in `Web.config`, we need to tell MVC to use your custom base class:

```
<pages pageBaseType="MyNamespace.Views.MyViewPage">
```

It sounds like a lot of trouble, but you gain some serious functionality for all this work.  Now in your view, you can set any display hint you want as follows:

```
@{ DisplayHints.ShowBanner = true; }
```

And in your layout, you can access it just as easily:

```
@if( DisplayHints.ShowBanner ) {
  <div>My banner....</div>
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting, but ViewData still has the same weak typing issues as ViewBag, and you went to a lot more trouble to get there.

Comment: I like this solution.. and I don't think it's a "lot more trouble" to extend the `WebViewPage`

Comment: Maess, yes, `ViewData` has the same weak typing issues as `ViewBag`.  However, instead of saving a bunch of display hints as weakly typed variables, you are only saving one object, in which you can put as many strongly-typed things as you want, including more complicated structures.  In my application, that `DisplayHints` class contains upwards of twenty members...all strongly typed.

Answer (score 3):

Having a model for your layout is not a good idea as it will force all views to use that model.  However, you could put that type of information into the ViewBag and have the value populated in the constructor of one of your controller bases.

Comment: You could even have a base controller that always put the variable in the ViewBag

Comment: Of course, I wasn't sure if the OP was always going to use the same controller base.

Comment: if you can put the variable in the viewbag, why can't you strongly-typedly put it in the controller itself?

Comment: Views don't have access to the controller directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a SECTION in your Layout, and then if your View is responsible to "fill" that section... your view can place the HTML in that section.

Here you can see a detailed step by step tutorial on using SECTIONS:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If your partial needs to permanently modify the Layout variable.  One option is to modify the ViewBag prior to loading the Layout:

```
@{
    ViewData["ShowBanner"] = false;
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```